# Do multiple issuances of a taproot asset, using the same group_key, count conceptually as the same asset, even if they have different asset_ids?

Tags: taproot, decentralized-assets, taproot-assets

I am trying to understand the minting of Taproot Assets.

In particular I want to understand how to mint more of an existing asset, i.e. add to the existing supply of that asset.

I am experimenting with Taproot Assets using `tapd` version `0.3.2-alpha`:

```
$ tapcli --version
tapcli version 0.3.2-alpha.rc1 commit=v0.3.2-beta.rc1-2-g3757262
```

I have managed to create assets on Testnet using the MintAsset API endpoint:

https://lightning.engineering/api-docs/api/taproot-assets/mint/mint-asset/

For example, I can send the following REST message to create an asset:

```
{
    "short_response": false,
    "asset": {
        "asset_type": 0, // Normal type
        "asset_version": 1, // ASSET_VERSION_V1
        "name": "My asset",
        "amount": 1000,
        "asset_meta": {
            "data": "123456", // Metadata relevant to the asset
            "type": 0 // META_TYPE_OPAQUE
        },
        "new_grouped_asset": true
    }
}
```

This will successfully enqueue the minting into the next batch, and once the batch is committed, `1000` units of the asset are created, with an `asset_id` and a `group_key`. Let's say the `group_key` was `0123456789ABCDEF`.

Suppose I want now to mint `500` more units of the same asset. If I send the following to the MintAsset API:

```
{
    "short_response": false,
    "asset": {
        "asset_type": 0, // normal
        "asset_version": 1, // ASSET_VERSION_V1
        "name": "My asset",
        "amount": 500,
        "asset_meta": {
            "data": "123456", // Metadata relevant to the asset
            "type": 0 // META_TYPE_OPAQUE
        },
        "grouped_asset": true,
        "group_key": "0123456789ABCDEF", // the hypothetical group_key hex
    }
}
```

Then this will mint `500` units of a **NEW** `asset_id`, but using the same `group_key`.

I can now get the balance of the group (`1500`) with:

```
tapcli assets balance --by_group --group_key 0123456789ABCDEF
```

Or I can get the balance resulting from each issuance (`1000` or `500`) with

```
tapcli assets balance --asset_id ABCDEF0123456789
```

*And now my question:*

- Should I think of these two assets (which have different `asset_id`s but the same `group_key`), as one asset conceptually, because they are in the same group now?
- Or is there another way to issue more of the same asset, so that multiple issuances have the same `asset_id`?

I hope my question makes sense. Please let me know if I have misunderstood something, or if my question is not clear.

Comment: I just now watched a YouTube video which seems to indicate that multiple issuances are supposed to have different asset_ids, and are grouped together only by the group_key. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FccI6j0mxuE&t=509s I'm going to leave this question here in case someone can give a more authoritative answer, but I think this is it...